# New view doesn't load in Spring MVC after request from jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have little confuse problem with Spring MVC. My view doesn't load after request from jquery. Controller is called, but view on web browser doesn't change.

Explain step by step what I do:

1. Click button with jquery script:

   ```
   $(function() {
     $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: '/admin/delete',
           type: 'GET',
       }); 
       //location.href = '/admin/delete/';
     });
   });
   ```
2. My controller is activated (I see log:'Admin delete GET'):

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/delete/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String deleteGet(Model model) {

      log.debug("Admin delete GET");

      return "home";
   }
   ```
3. View "home" doesn't load :( why?

If I remove lines in jquery script with ajax and remain location.href, view "home" will be loaded.

```
    $(function() {
        $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
            location.href = '/admin/delete/';
        });
    });
```

View: Boostrap

Spring Boot : 1.2.2

Java: 1.8

Sitemesh: 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Modify `deleteGet` to return `ModelAndView` and then inside of your function create model and view object and return it:

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
model.setViewName("home");
return model;
```

also can be a problem with mappings. Does log show any error? I suggest you to provide also `<bean id="viewResolver">` configuration. It must be defined in `*-servlet.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I change my code for your proposition:

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
model.setViewName("home");
return model;
```

but it nothing change.

Note that if I call "public String deleteGet(Model model)" from normal FORM in JSP or using "location.href = '/admin/delete/';" "home" view loading quit normal without problems.

My viewResolver for Spring Boot is look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {


   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
       resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
       return resolver;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax should be,

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/admin/delete',
    type: 'GET',
    success:function(viewName){
         location.href = viewName; //add prefix to your view name in case if it is needed
    }
});
```